# How to pass two variables to php,mySQL using ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
$("#submit_login").click(function(){
       var username=$('input[name=user_email]');
       var password=$('input[name=user_password]');
       var data;
       data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "newExam.php", 
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                     alert("Form submitted successfully");
                }
              });     

   });
```

How to give the data variable so that we can fetch it in PHP using $_REQUEST?
The above representation of the data variable shows an error.

Comment: Could you add the error?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the data as json,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "newExam.php",
    data:  {
        name: username,
        pwd: password
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Form submitted successfully");
    }
});
```

Also,  names should match the parameters in the function.

Answer (score 1):

**Client Side**

```
$("#submit_login").click(function(){

       var username=$("input[name='user_email']").val();
       var password=$("input[name='user_password']").val();

         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "newExam.php", 
                data: {name : username, pwd : password },
                success: function(data) {
                     alert("Form submitted successfully");
                }
              });     

   });
```

**Server Side**

```
<?php

// file : newExam.php     

// to view  post array
if(!empty($_POST))
{
   print_r($_POST);
}

// access individual element
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
   echo $_POST['name'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

*The above representation of the data variable shows an error.*

Absolutely. That is correct because there is an error. You have a variable and you are assigning a query string with `:` where it should be `=`:

```
data= "name="+username+"&pwd="+password;
```

But this is not a good idea because you have to post the values not the input objects. username is an html input element, instead you should post an object like:

```
$("#submit_login").click(function(){
   var username=$('input[name=user_email]').val();
   var password=$('input[name=user_password]').val();
   var data = {name:username, pwd:password};
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json", // <---make sure you return json from the php side.
     url: "newExam.php", 
     data: data,
     success: function(data) {
         alert("Form submitted successfully");
     }
   });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors dont look right to me.

```
   var username=$('input[name="user_email"]');
   var password=$('input[name="user_password"]');
```

Note the double quotes around the input name attributes

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code format:

```
data: {name : username, pwd : password }
```